# Existence of function (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $f (\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{n}{n+1}, n=2,3,\dots$ , where $D$ is unit disc in the complex plane $\mathbb C$?
This is a question of complex analysis. Please provide a hint to solve it.

Comment: Should the function be holomorphic or meromorphic?

Comment: It's not given.

Comment: Is it given that $n \in \mathbb{N}_1 = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, didn't saw it before.

Comment: $$f(y)=\frac1{y+1}$$ ??? Of course this is not defined at $y=-1$ but since you don't seem to demand anything about $f$, you can define it as whatever you want outside of the points $1/n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Set $z=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $n=\frac{1}{z}$ and hence $$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{z}}{\frac{1}{z}+1}=\frac{1}{1+z}$$

Define $$g(z)=f(z)-\frac{1}{1+z}$$

Now, if $f$ is holomorphic then so is $g$. Since $g(\frac{1}{n})=0$ by the identity theorem $g=0$. This means.....

Answer (score 0):

Without any more requirements we can just take $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{n}{n+1}$
for $n\in \mathbb{N}_1$ and $f(z) = 0$ when $z \not\in \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_1 \}.$

Comment: This should probably be a comment with the word "holomorphic" mentioned.

Comment: @zhw. What you wrote already is a comment.